# nestjs graphql sdl first generated resolver classes should be implemented partially

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

Using Nest.js GraphQL in SDL first fashion. Each module has its own *.graphql file. I'm generating types using this;

```
import { GraphQLDefinitionsFactory } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { join } from 'path';

const definitionsFactory = new GraphQLDefinitionsFactory();
definitionsFactory.generate({
  typePaths: ['./src/**/*.graphql'],
  path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/graphql.ts'),
  outputAs: 'class',
});
```

Ultimately, a graphql.ts file created with **IQuery** & **IMutation** classes. All resolver stubs are in the same class. Each resolver class in each module should extend these abstract IQuery & IMutation partially. However, typescript expect us to implement all abstract methods.

```
export class QueryResolvers extends IQuery {
```

Is it possible to extend partially?

Answer (score 0):

`Partial<IQuery>` & `Partial<IMutation>` did it. Like;

````
export class CountryQueryResolvers implements Partial<IQuery>
```
````